# Add Nibble to an array of bytes

Tags: java, arrays, byte, padding, nibble

I have an array of 9 bytes in Java but my function need to return an array of size 10. The difference I need to pad with Nibbles.

If a nibble is a half of a byte, can I simply add a (byte) 0 to an array at the end or adding 2 nibbles instead will make a difference? Is there a difference between 2 nibbles and a (byte) 0 in this case?

Comment: This depends very much on your specific requirements.

Comment: @chrylis, thank you very much for responding. This is a requirement and I am confused about it... If I need to fill the space with nibbles and a nibble is half a byte, why not fill the space with (byte) 0?... I am confused why use nibble, unless they make some kind of difference, which I cannot see...

Comment: are the nibbles both supposed to be at the end?

Comment: @JeremyKahan yes!

Comment: There are two reasons why this question is being downvoted. 1) the obvious nature of the question suggests a lack of research 2) missing code and/or details of how the padding is to be implemented, e.g. all zero bits at the end of the array.

Comment: @PatrickParker thank you!... I am still not clear.. If I am working with an array of bytes, how can I even add half a byte into it. My understanding is that array of bytes can take byte as an entry. Can I even put 8.5 bits into an array of bytes and then check the array for "length" and get back 8.5 as value?...

Comment: the array.length will always be 10, as you stated in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a nibble is a half of a byte, can I simply add a (byte) 0 to an
>   array at the end or adding 2 nibbles instead will make a difference?
>
> Is there a difference between 2 nibbles and a (byte) 0 in this case?

No there is no difference since a byte (8 bits) is made up 2 *x* nibble (4 bits).

> Can I even put 8.5 bits into an array of bytes and then check the
>   array for "length" and get back 8.5 as value?

For 8.5 bits? At this point it will be returned as length of 2 bytes. If you mean 8.5 bytes then it's returned as 9 bytes.

**Remember** The smallest data-type is a `byte` not a `nibble`!! By declaring a type `byte` (even with no value assigned) you've automatically made 8 bits of `0000 0000`. Nibbles just make it easier to visualize the bits within a byte's value (when written in hex notation).

For example the single byte value `0xF0` can be visualised as two nibbles of `1111 0000`. Now for a byte `0xBA`, if you wanted just one nibble you'll have to make the byte as either `0x0B` or `0x0A`...

> I have an array of 9 bytes in Java but my function need to return an
>   array of size 10. The difference I need to pad with Nibbles.

Your function returns 80 bits. With 9 bytes you'll have a total 72 bits so you pad with extra 8 bits which means add one byte extra of `zero` value (eg: `0x00`).

- In the case of some *8 & half* bytes, you should actually create 9 bytes (72bits) but only update the first 68 bits (8.5 bytes).
- Best logic is to just declare a byte array with length of 10 (*ie:* 80 zero bits). Then you can update as many or as few bits as you need within this total  allocated space. 
  This way *"I have an array of 9 bytes"* becomes *"I create an array of 10 bytes and only update 9 or even 8.5 bytes"* which leaves you with automatic padding of those unused 1 or 1.5 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

So your question is if nibble 0000 adjacent to nibble 0000 equals byte 00000000 ?

Yes.

When you write down the individual bits like that it should be obvious I think.

The need for padding with partial bytes will only arise when you are storing data with partial bytes. For example, let's assume I limited my character set to only a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and the space character. That would enable me to use only 4 bits to encode each character.

Comment: Patrick, thank you for your response. No, I wondered why use Nibbles in this case? This is my first time coming across Nibbles and I wondered why filling empty space with Nibbles makes a difference... and I do not understand why people are down voting this question...

Comment: @Simplyi Presumably the nibbles would come into play if you were returning 8.5 bytes for example.

Comment: I see... I am working with Strings and then Bytes out of these String values and have never come across a situation when I would get a half a byte... anyways, thank you Patrick!

Comment: @Simplyi perhaps you are working with a limited character set which could permit encoding each character with only 4 bits. That gives you 64 characters including null (0000).